# How to receive email and process it using PHP

Tags: php, perl, email

Can anyone suggest the methods I could use...

I m on shared hosting now (cpanel)... I have access to perl modules, ruby, (No idea how they work)

Answer (score 1):

The [IMAP](http://www.php.net/imap) extension is used for that. Either by having a real mailbox you check, or by letting the mailserver pipe emails to your your script & parsing the parts of the email with the provided funstions.

Comment: umm.. I just want to pipe emails (im not saving any of it) .... process it via php...

Comment: need a little help on functions that i could use to catch emails... i am kinda new to this..

Answer (score 0):

[`PEAR_Mail_MimeDecode`](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mimedecode.php) class from Pear. Is the real solution.

> Possible Duplicate:
>   [Process RECEIVED email attatchment with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994493/process-received-email-attatchment-with-php)

Comment: @shamittomar: why editing an answer saying the question is a possible duplicate? Just vote to close, or add a comment.

Comment: @Wrikken, I just fixed the formatting issues in the answer. The `Possible Duplicate` was already given by the original answerer (JapanPro).

Comment: @Wrikken, Also, this  looks like a possible duplicate only ..... not exact duplicate. Because in the other question, only attachments are processed but here he wants to process everything.

Comment: OK, I was to hasty & not checking things properly, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a on a shared hosting system it is possibly easiest to let someone like http://cloudmailin.com or http://smtp2web.com/ send the email to your app via a webhook.

You will then need to use something like [Mail_MimeDecode](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mimedecode.php) to actually parse the message you receive and extract the content you want to use.